# How to force the expiration of all SSH certs?

Tags: ssh, certificate

I just ran into a problem where I have too many SSH keys somewhere (not just in my `~/.ssh/` directory).  Is there a way to count or otherwise force the expiration of potentially stale ones?

https://serverfault.com/a/256083/141061

Comment: AFAIK, SSH keys do not have an expiry date associated with them - they are not a cert ( keys != certs). You may be able to discern older keys from the timestamp associated with the file. You should advise what ssh client you are using.

Comment: Why have you linked to a Server Fault answer?  What is confusing by that answer on Server Fault?  Keys are designed to be trusted until they are replaced.